# Close AlertDialog when user selects an option

Tags: android, gridview, android-alertdialog

I have this working piece of code for selecting a number from a GridView that's inside an AlertDialog:

```
public void iconSelect (View v){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    GridView gridview = new GridView(this);

    List<Integer>  mList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        mList.add(i);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mList);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
    gridview.setNumColumns(3);
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Chosen: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    builder.setView(gridview);
    builder.setTitle("Icon selector");
    builder.show();
}
```

My goal is that when the user selects a number from the gridview then the dialog get closed. Right now it lets the user click the number on the gridview and show the toast many times as the user wants until he presses back button.

What should I do?
I'm looking for a method similar to builder.close() or builder.dismiss() to be executed inside the listener. (Making builder a final variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `builder.show()` or `builder.create()` to hold an instance of `AlertDialog` in order to dismiss it after that

Try the following code:

```
public void iconSelect (View v){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    GridView gridview = new GridView(this);

    List<Integer>  mList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        mList.add(i);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mList);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
    gridview.setNumColumns(3);

    builder.setView(gridview);
    builder.setTitle("Icon selector");
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Chosen: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice ! It worked perfectly ! Thank you Abdallah. I'll take note of this. I didn't know that I was doing _voiding_ in `builder.show()`